# Loading data from pyspark into a bigquery table but getting a schema incompatible error

Tags: pyspark, google-bigquery

I'm trying to load data into a bigquery table from a pyspark dataframea and am hitting the following error:

```
    1) [Guice/ErrorInCustomProvider]: IllegalArgumentException: BigQueryConnectorException$InvalidSchemaException: Destination table's schema is not compatible with dataframe's schema
E                     at BigQueryDataSourceWriterModule.provideDirectDataSourceWriterContext(BigQueryDataSourceWriterModule.java:60)
E                     while locating BigQueryDirectDataSourceWriterContext
E                   
E                   Learn more:
E                     https://github.com/google/guice/wiki/ERROR_IN_CUSTOM_PROVIDER
E                   
E                   1 error
```

I've tried making the schemas match, as shown:

Pyspark dataframe schema

```
root
 |-- key_column: string (nullable = false)
 |-- column_a: string (nullable = false)
 |-- column_b: string (nullable = true)
 |-- column_c: string (nullable = false)
```

Bigquery table schema

```
{"fields":[{"metadata":{},"name":"key_column","nullable":false,"type":"string"},{"metadata":{},"name":"column_a","nullable":false,"type":"string"},{"metadata":{},"name":"column_b","nullable":true,"type":"string"},{"metadata":{},"name":"column_c","nullable":false,"type":"string"}],"type":"struct"}
```

What do I need to modify/correct to make this load work?

Comment: The order of columns also affect how this logic recognizes the schema. Can you check on your real setup if both schemas absolutely identical (names, nullable, order of fields)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Alexander's comment, I verified that my columns were indeed in the right order and it gave me the idea to try one other thing. It turns out that casing is important.  I had a mixed case column name in the dataframe (i.e. column_B) and an all lower cased column name in the table (i.e. column_b).  Modifying the dataframe column name corrected the issue.